# How do i get the last value in the same name Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make like this
[Hope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQXD2.png)

But i just got like this
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETHoo.png)

What should i do ? here is my code. Thx for help

PHP

```
if(empty($_GET['jenis'])){
$jenis = "";}
else{
$jenis      = ($_GET['jenis']);
}

if(empty($_GET['kategori'])){
$kategori ="";}
else{
$kategori       = ($_GET['kategori']);
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
        function jeniss(){
        document.getElementById('keywords').submit();   
        }
        function kategorii(){
        document.getElementById('keywords').submit();   
        }   

</script>
```

HTML

```
<form id="keywords">

    <div class="single-sidebar">
        <h3 class="sidebar-title">Jenis</h3>
        <div class="sidebar-list">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="jenis" value="11" onclick="jeniss();" <?php if ($jenis == 11) { echo 'checked'; } ?>> <a> Kos  </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="jenis" value="12" onclick="jeniss();" <?php if ($jenis == 12) { echo 'checked'; } ?>> <a> Kontrakan </a> </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-sidebar">
        <h3 class="sidebar-title">Kategori</h3>
        <div class="sidebar-list">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="kategori" value="21" onclick="kategorii();" <?php if ($kategori == 21) { echo 'checked'; } ?>> <a> Khusus Pria </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="kategori" value="22" onclick="kategorii();" <?php if ($kategori == 22) { echo 'checked'; } ?>> <a> Khusus Wanita </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Campuran </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> 2 Lantai </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> 3 Lantai </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> 4 Lantai atau Lebih </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-sidebar">
        <h3 class="sidebar-title">Wilayah</h3>
        <div class="sidebar-list">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kecamatan Bunaken </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kecamatan Bunaken Kepulauan </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kecamatan Malalayang </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kecamatan Paal Dua </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kecamatan Mapanget </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kecamatan Sario </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kecamatan Singkil </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kecamatan Tikala </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kecamatan Tuminting </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kecamatan Wanea </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kecamatan Wenang </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="single-sidebar">
        <h3 class="sidebar-title">Fasilitas</h3>
        <div class="sidebar-list">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> AC </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kamar Mandi Dalam </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Garasi Mobil </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Garasi Motor </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Meja </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kursi </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Lemari </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kipas Angin </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Tempat Tidur </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Air PAM </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Air Sumur </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Listrik Prabayar </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Listrik Pascabayar </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kolam Renang </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Kolam Ikan </a> </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"> <a> Ruang Tamu </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Anyway the code is not complete yet the php code will be the code for calling data from sql. Then when i check the code, the last value in checkbox with the name is not saved. The question is how i can make an action which that when i submit 2 values in the same name of checkbox is not removing the previous value in javascript. Thx for helping.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/) — Don't substitute `<a>` elements!

Answer (score -1):

`GET` url Params are supposed to be a simple key value.. when a key is used twice the latest value will override all the others..

you might wanna use POST to send an `array` or an `object`.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. Query strings and POST data can both include multiple fields with the same name.